# Why do cells jump when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I work with `UITableView` with cell that hold label with `numberOfLines = 0,` it means that cell can show 1 line or 20 lines.

my problem is that the scroll not smooth.

** `estimatedRowHeight` didn't helped.

```
class SingleTopicControllerV2: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellId, for: indexPath) as! ReplyCellV2
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.setupCellWithReply(reply: reply, user: self.user, index: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

}

class ReplyCellV2: UITableViewCell {
func setupCellWithReply(reply: Reply, user: CurrensUserRealm, index: Int) {
    self.index = index

    if RealmService.shared.realm {
        self.reply = reply
        self.usernameBtn.setTitle(reply.owner.firstName, for: .normal)
        self.contentLabel.text = reply.content
        self.dateLabel.text = reply.time
    }
    self.setupRole(roleStr: reply.owner.role)
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Like the viewcontroller and cell? Also shouldn't you be using `estimatedHeightForRow` delegate?

Comment: I tried, both table.estimatedRowHeight and with the delegate func.
didn't helped for me.

Comment: _Can you share more of your code?_

Comment: Is `RealmService.shared.realm` a network call?

Comment: no, Local database

Comment: Have you edited func setupCellWithReply(reply: Reply, user: CurrensUserRealm, index: Int) {
I cannot see where you use user inside

Comment: @claude31 just self.user = user

Comment: Could you try to replace the code in this func by some predefined values (to check if data access is causing the delay); probably simulating the variable number of lines from 1 to 20 that you mention.